# Geocoder - Geocode the data in the controler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I am using the Geocoder gem and i want to geocode the location (city, state) and get the lat lng in the controller.

I am doing this and am getting the following error.

```
<%= @geo = Geocoder.coordinates("Los Angeles").inspect %>
<%= puts @geo.join(",") %>
```

Error:
    undefined method `join' for "[46.7225341, 8.9635602]":String

I want to get the lat and lng as a comma seperated string to save in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to use inspect here. It probably casts it to a String which doesn't have a join method. Also usually geocoding is done on the model with a before_save callback and not in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily geocode the address in model using `after_validation`.

Just like this.

```
      # app/models/venue.rb
        geocoded_by :address
        after_validation :geocode
```

By this way, You can save the latitude and longitude attributes to the corresponding model.

Comment: i am seeing that it geocodes wrong values as well. any idea how to handle it

Comment: @HarshaMV that depends on the geocode API, By default it uses google maps API. You can configure them `config/initializers/geocoder.rb` file. If you don't have config file, generate one using `rails generate geocoder:config`